# ASP.NET -- C# MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I have something a site that **a user inputs a image with a title** and i want to display it on the website. That title for that image.

Atm **I'm saving to a folder and displaying all images** but I cant display the title. It just doesnt appear when I do `<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.title)</h2>`

Something like this: But I wanted the title of the post.
https://i.gyazo.com/17828889116a77983f70fd8c8a4c2ebf.png

***Maybe I need to save the image to the database? Please help me on this.***

View:

```
    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.title)</h2>
    <div class="row">       
        <div class="col-md-8 portfolio-item">
            <img class="portrait" src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="Hejsan" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Model

```
 [Table("MemeImages")]
public class UploadFileModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string location { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Images { get; set; }

    public int contentLength { get; set; }
    public string contentType { get; set; }

    public string userID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Describe your post...")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    public void SavetoDatabase(UploadFileModel file)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();                    
        db.uploadedFiles.Add(file);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public class MemesController : Controller
{

    private string memesDirectory = "~/Content/Images/Memes/";

    // GET: Memes/Upload
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        var uploadFile = new UploadFileModel();
        return View(uploadFile);
    }

    // GET: Memes/Hot
    public ActionResult Hot(UploadFileModel uploadFileModel)
    {
        //Select every image on the server memesdirectory and posts it
        uploadFileModel.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(memesDirectory)).Select(fn => memesDirectory + Path.GetFileName(fn));
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Memes/Trending
    public ActionResult Trending()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Memes/Fresh
    public ActionResult Fresh()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(UploadFileModel uploadModel)
    {         
        if(Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            if(file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //saves image to the server
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(memesDirectory), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);

                //saves image-related data to the database
                uploadModel.userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                uploadModel.location = path;
                uploadModel.contentType = file.ContentType;
                uploadModel.contentLength = file.ContentLength;


                //saves to the database
                uploadModel.SavetoDatabase(uploadModel);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your title is - nothing more than some tags and shows zero effort on your side to think up a meaningfull question

Comment: I did that and it got 3 views. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    uploadFileModel.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(memesDirectory)).Select(fn => memesDirectory + Path.GetFileName(fn));
    return View();
```

likely needs to be changed to:

```
    // Add code here to get uploadFileModel from the databases
    uploadFileModel.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(memesDirectory)).Select(fn => memesDirectory + Path.GetFileName(fn));
    uploadFileModel.title = "something you want"; // this line may not be necessary if getting it from the database did this for you already

    return View(uploadFileModel);
```

Comment: The titles are on the database. How do I retreive them and insert each title for each image?

Comment: A foreach loop over `new ApplicationDbContext().uploadedFiles` is probably where you want to start.